# Denominator degrees of freedom (when using lmer) are different in loop than outside loop

Tags: r, loops, lme4

I am looping an lmer function over 20+ y variables, with 159 rows of observations. When I run an lmer function inside the loop, denominator degrees of freedom are lost. Outside the loop (or even if I specify one y variable *inside* the loop), denominator df is as expected.

I have a df with 20 y variables for plants in two chambers with 4 treatments (replicated in both treatements).

```
lmer_test <- lmer(leaves_mean~Treatment + (1|Chamber), data = df)
aov_test <- anova(lmer_test)
aov_test
```

This gives:

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
Treatment 97.593  32.531     3   153  1.1966 0.3131
```

I have a loop:

```
for(u in colnames(df)[6:ncol(df)])
{
 Y_variable_Rex <- names(df[u])
 lmer_u_Rex <-lmer(get(u) ~ Treatment  + (1|Chamber), data = df)
 aov_u_Rex <- anova(lmer_u_Rex) 
 aov_u_Rex
}
```

That gives

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF      DenDF    F value Pr(>F)
Treatment 208420   69473     3 4.6406e-14 3.5911e+31      1
```

If I specify the exact code as outside the loop (replacing get(u) with "leaves_mean")... I get the correct result:

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
Treatment 97.593  32.531     3   153  1.1966 0.3131
```

The "get_u" specification should result in exactly the same result inside the loop. What is happening that makes the *denominator degrees of freedom* different (0)?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question...
The loop was reporting denominator df for a *different* variable (the last one).
There are missing values in that column as that was a y variable of *sampled* values, with many missing rows.
I was able to reproduce the error and then resolve it within the loop.
I was approaching de-bugging here like you might do in a Matlab loop (step-wise through each row), which is *not* a good method for fixing R loops.
Thank you for reading this question and considering answering!

Comment: hmm.  That doesn't entirely explain what's going on to me.  I would say as general best practice that `get(u)` is a little bit dicey because it can be hard to guess where (i.e., what environment) R is going to retrieve it from.  I would suggest that (inside the loop) `form <- reformulate(c("Treatment", "(1|Chamber")), response = u); lmer(form, data = df)` would be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! I'll give that a whirl and maybe reformat my other loops based on this. You are right, `get(u)` does become dicey especially if I was not careful and used a loop with u elsewhere... in any case I appreciate your assistance!